# Extract all natural areas from osm

Tags: r, openstreetmap, osmosis

using osmosis I want to extract all natural areas from an xml osm map

```
osmosis --read-xml map.osm --way-key-value keyValueList="natural" --write-xml out.osm
```

When reading the output map out.osm (using R and readOGR), this map contains only points, while I expected multiplepolygons.

```
library(rgdal)
natural <- readOGR('out.osm')
```

Am I doing something wrong?